# PHPStorm 8 and PHPUnit problems with @runInSeparateProcess

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

I am running phpunit (composer provisioned and version 4.8) from PHPStorm 8. Usually it works fine but whenever I need to use the @runInSeparateProcess annotation it starts screaming this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Util_Configuration' not found in - on line 334

Call Stack:
0.0013     395808   1. {main}() -:0
```

The PHPUnit configuration on the IDE is the following:

- Language & Frameworks > PHP > PHPunit: custom autoloader pointing to *codebase*/vendor/autoload.php
- Run/Debug Configuration: alternative configuration file which point to my local phpunit.xml

This is the content of the configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.2/phpunit.xsd"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="./vendor/autoload.php"
         backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false">

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="My Project">
            <directory>./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">./src</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

The tests run as expected from the command line with the same phpunit executable and the same configuration file.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently removing all dependencies and re-installing phpunit from composer (phpunit 4.8.6) solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A modification of the fix the folks over at Drupal are using (https://www.drupal.org/node/2597814)

Add to the top of your boostrap file:

```
if (!defined('PHPUNIT_COMPOSER_INSTALL')) {
    define('PHPUNIT_COMPOSER_INSTALL', __DIR__ . '/path/to/composer/vendors/dir/autoload.php');
}
```

I tried many other methods, including upgrading PHPStorm and up/down-grading PHPUnit.  This works.